# Regex Help - specific years or range of years

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I'm not very good with these. I can't figure out how to match this scenario: 2012,2015 (specific  years) 2013-2015 (year range) 2013-* (any date after 2013 i.e., future years). I can get the first two scenarios to match but not the last.

/^[0-9]{4}(?:[,-*][0-9]{4})*,?$/

2012,2013,2014-2015,**2016-*** (no match)

Comment: Not a good idea to match date-time with regex. Use functions in respective programming language instead.

Comment: split the string by comma, then check each of the values you got against what you are looking for

Comment: Ah, didn't think of splitting. I'll give that a shot!

Comment: It really helps to specify the language for the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can split by comma and check the years one by one:

```js
let s = "2012,2013,2014-2015,2016-*,foo,292992,322,2103-238";
let split = s.split(',');

for (let x of split) {
  console.log(determine(x));
}

// or to check if all are ok:
let allOk = split.every(determine);
console.log("every: ", allOk);

function determine(year) {
  let y = year.split('-');
  if (!y[0].match(/^\d{4}$/)) return false;
  if (typeof y[1] === 'undefined' || y[1] === '*') return true;
  return determine(y[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that works for your year formats

```
[0-9]{4}\-?(?:[0-9]{4}|\*)?
```

[check](https://regex101.com/r/RytvFQ/1)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to handle the whole thing. Since the comma can't be optional if you have more years and you don't want to end in a comma, you must repeat the year term:

```
^[0-9]{4}(?:-(?:[0-9]{4}|\*))?(?:,[0-9]{4}(?:-(?:[0-9]{4}|\*))?)*$
```